# spring boot return escaped json

Tags: json, spring-boot

my code

```
@GetMapping(value = {"/metadata"}, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
@ResponseBody
public String getMetadata() {
    return  dppService.getMetadata();
}
```

the method getMetadata will just return a json string. it just read data from the json file, and it is in another library can not be changed.

But when call this api, i got the follow reponse:

```
"{\"Namespace\":\"com.xxx\"...
```

the json string was escaped.
expected:

```
"{"Namespace":"com.xxx"...
```

How could i make it return the right json? BTW, our other services also return a json string in the controller, but their response will not be escaped which is so confused for me.

Comment: What is the return type of `dppService.getMetadata()` in your code ? Are you manually converting the pojo to  a json string ?

Comment: @Ananthapadmanabhan ,its string. This method just read a json file as a string and then return

Comment: If so try the second method that I provided in the answer.

Comment: that's madness, who will use escaped JSON.... damn. Its a not an easy fix issue. Spring team need to look into this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

root cause:
There is a configuration file in the project:

```
 @Override
public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
    converters.add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(jacksonBuilder().build()));
    converters.stream()
            .filter(converter -> converter instanceof MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter)
            .findFirst()
            .ifPresent(converter -> ((MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter) converter).setDefaultCharset(UTF_8));
}
```

This configuration overrite the defualt jackson behavior. There are two ways to solve this issue:
1.Remove this configuration, then it will be the default behavior
2.Add the StringHttpMessageConverter in this configuration, see Ananthapadmanabhan's option2

Answer (score 1):

You could do this two ways:

From what I could understand you are having this issues because you might be returning the `json` as a `string` from from the service method  `dppService.getMetadata()` by converting it manually to a string. If so , change that and instead return a `POJO` class from the service method as well as the  controller, spring default jackson converter should automatically convert it to a json when the request is served. (I would suggest you go with this approach)

Another approach (the hacky less desirable one) if you still want to keep returning a string then you could configure the `StringMessageConverter` like below to accept json:

```
@Override
public void configureMessageConverters(
        List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
    StringHttpMessageConverter stringConverter = new StringHttpMessageConverter(
            Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
    stringConverter.setSupportedMediaTypes(Arrays.asList( //
            MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN, //
            MediaType.TEXT_HTML, //
            MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
    converters.add(stringConverter);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have already found the root cause. 
In our project we use spring boot and jackson in the library, Acutually by default spring boot will return the right json.
But one of my colleagues add a configuration and adpate the MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter, so that the json is escaped.
 Thanks a lot for your help